# getter and setter for int in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, macos

i am a new programmer of Objective C ... i have some problems in my code, i dont know why i am get an error...
this is my code:
Rectangle.h:

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>



 @interface Rectangle : NSObject
    {
        int width;
        int height;
    }
        @property(setter=setWidthOfRect: , getter=getWidth) int width;
        @property(setter=setHeightOfRect: , getter=getHeight) int height;
 @end
```

Rectangle.m:

```
#import "Rectangle.h"

@implementation Rectangle
    @synthesize width, height;
    @end
```

and this is main.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Rectangle.h"



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Rectangle *rect = [[Rectangle alloc] init];
        [rect setWidthOfRect:22];
        [rect setHeightOfRect:28];
     NSLog(@"the area is: %d", [rect getHeight] * [rect getWidth]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

and i am not get this: "the area is 616
any help please?

Comment: I made it, its giving right answer.

Comment: I think you are not watching LOG or it might be closed, means you are watching some other things, not console.

Comment: It looks ok, except some copy paste in above code, I am editing it.

Comment: it suddenly worked !! i dont know why doesnt worked before ! , thanks @Duaan

Comment: **One important note**: Obj-C doesn't use `get` Prefix in getters.

Comment: What is wrong with default setter and getter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use default getters/setters, just write your properties like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int width;
```

You don't even need to write `@synthesize` and ivars. Than you can use it like this:

```
object.width = 5; // or
[object setWidth:5];

int width = object.width; // or
int width = [object width];
```

Comment: Why do you use `nonatomic`? Do you care about performance that much or do you override setter or getter in here? Besides you don't need to use `assign` either because it's default for non-object properties which means that `@property int width;` is more than enough.

Comment: I use `atomic` only when I know that this this code will be used from multiple threads. In most cases, it's not. What about `assign`, this is only my code style preference. The code looks more accurate near the properties of other types (`weak`, `strong`). And Apple in their SDK headers use the same approach.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the extra ints above your properties width and height.  A property makes the data type you specify already and inside there you can define what the set property method name is and get property name as well as other property flags.